# New .csproj format - How to specify entire directory as "linked file" to a subdirectory?

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, csproj, .net-standard

With the new `.csproj` format (as well as the old), it is possible to add files as linked outside of the project folder:

```
 <EmbeddedResource Include="..\..\..\Demo\Sample.cs" Link="Resources\Sample.cs" />
```

It is also possible to use a glob pattern to include multiple files:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="..\..\..\Demo\*.cs" />
```

But how do you combine the two?

### What I Tried

1. `<EmbeddedResource Include="..\..\..\Demo\*.cs" Link="Resources\*.cs" />`
2. `<EmbeddedResource Include="..\..\..\Demo\*.cs" Link="Resources\*" />`
3. `<EmbeddedResource Include="..\..\..\Demo\*.cs" Link="Resources\" />`

The first two only create a single linked file (with exactly the name `*.cs` and `*` respectively). The third simply errors out.

Is there a way to combine globbing with linked files to a specific location in the target project? If not, how can I link all the files in a directory without knowing how many or what their names are?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

While this was previously possible using the `%(RecursiveDir)` metadata when using glob expansion ( `Link="Resources\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)"`), the 2.0.0 version of the .NET Core SDK allows the use of a new `LinkBase` metadata:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="..\..\..\Demo\**\*.cs" LinkBase="Resources" />
```

Note that you need to install the 2.0.0 in addition to the recently released VS 2017 15.3 (and ensure no `global.json` selects a lower version).

It was introduced with [this pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/pull/1246) which is probably the best documentation at the moment.

Comment: How would I specify the `MinimumVisualStudioVersion` to enforce this? I tried using [this script](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dmx/2017/06/13/how-to-get-visual-studio-2017-version-number-and-edition/) to lookup my version (`15.3.26730.12`), but when I put this value into the solution file, VS 2017 15.3 doesn't open it. Also tried 15.3, but that doesn't work either. This seems like a reasonable thing to add to this answer given the minimum requirement of 15.3. Is there a list of these version numbers somewhere?

Comment: Not really possible at the moment. The problem is you don't just need 15.3, you also need the 2.0.0 SDK (which isn't included in 15.3). https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2350

Comment: .NET Core SDK 2.x is included in later versions of VS such as 15.7.2 so you may get a suitable .NET Core SDK version but applying the latest VS 2017 update, provided that is an option for you. - @martin-ullrich you just saved us a large amount of work/risk! Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

I got this working for me (linking all svg-files in an external dir to a solution-subfolder) with a hint from this [site](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6fa1991c-e78d-4999-b1a6-4907509b7387/using-wildcards-with-link?forum=msbuild). Only the `%(Parent.Filename)` didn't work for me (got a CS1508), so I replaced with `%(Filename)%(Extension)`.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Parent Include="C:\Path\To\My\SVG\Dir\*.svg" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="@(Parent)">
        <Link>Resources\%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
    </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```