# Markdown documentation in Visual Studio Solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, markdown

I started a new project using c# and Visual Studio 2017. My goal is to manage the documentation inside Visual Studio to have all files in one place and a complete and easy accessable history in TFS/Git.
I have the code in the `src` folder, the test projects in the `test` folder, the documentation as Markdown files in the `docs` folder (I use [Markdown Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.MarkdownEditor)). There is also a Readme.md in the root folder:

[image]

Now there are some problems:

- The structure in Visual Studio is different than in the file system. All md-Files I create in Visual Studio are placed in the root directory of the Solution. I could create the files in Windows Explorer and add "Existing Item" but this
  is a pain.
- I can move md-files in Visual Studio but they won't move in the file system.
- All file references are saved in the sln-file which would change a lot. I'd like to avoid that.

I read about creating an empty c# project and disable building for that project but that seems like a hack too.

Are there some recommendations to manage documentation files in Visual Studio?

Comment: I have a question about managing livestock using Gimp... I'd like to put pictures of all my cows inside layers in Gimp without actually saving them in the .xcf file

Comment: @Nyerguds Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately I don't get what you want to tell me. Is this a question?

Comment: I'm wondering if you are using the correct tool for this job. You know source control services like Git can perfectly be used on bare folders, right? You don't need a solution file for that. And, the project file is your project's file table. Of course a file can't exist in the project without being referenced in there; it's what the file _does_.

Comment: That said, I have never heard of the solution's tree being different from the file tree. Are you sure you are using the Solution Explorer, and not the Class View?

Comment: I know Visual Studio is no documentation tool but everything I need is available. Just some things are annoying but still better than editing the files with a different tool.

Comment: Solution folders are not created in the file system. Folders in projects are created in the file system but I try not to use a .csproj or something like that.

Comment: Then... doesn't simply "making a project inside the solution and putting everything in there" solve all your issues? afaik that's the way solutions are meant to be used anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45800697/new-csproj-format-how-to-specify-entire-directory-as-linked-file-to-a-subdi), it is possible to use the *linked file* feature in Visual Studio 2017 to link **an entire directory**, provided you are using the [new `.csproj` project format](http://www.natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/) and you have the .NET Core 2.0 SDK installed in addition to Visual Studio 2017 15.3+.

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="..\..\..\docs\**\*.md" LinkBase="docs" />
```

This will link a `docs` subfolder using the relative path of your project to a folder within the project named `docs` (the LinkBase). Every time you add, remove, or change a file in the `docs` folder or nested folder, the changes will be recognized by Visual Studio (it may prompt you to update the file in Visual Studio if it is already open).

[image]

Note that you can use this feature on other [MSBuild Project Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629388.aspx) besides `EmbeddedResource` as well, such as `Content`, `Compile`, or `None`.

### Projects

Technically, Visual Studio solution files *are* projects. You can see this by opening the `.sln` file in a text editor:

```
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "build", "build", "{4016BDAB-6C33-4D1E-9439-57B416EA45D5}"
    ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
        build.bat = build.bat
        build\build.ps1 = build\build.ps1
        src\CommonAssemblyInfo.cs = src\CommonAssemblyInfo.cs
        TestTargetFramework.proj = TestTargetFramework.proj
        Version.proj = Version.proj
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
```

Unfortunately, the [`.sln` format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165951.aspx) doesn't provide many options. As you can see in [Hack the Project and Solution Files](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/dotnet/excerpt/vshacks_chap1/index.html?page=4), the `ProjectSection` simply lists the dependencies of the project, and optionally has the ability to specify a "real" relative file path. But that is pretty much it. And according to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267200/visual-studio-solutions-folder-as-real-folders), it is not possible to link a directory to another directory in a `.sln` file.

The only difference between the above Solution Items "Project" and a `.csproj` project is that the latter shifts control of where the files are added to the `.csproj` (MSBuild) file.

```
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "MyProject", 
"src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj", "{3A0AA37E-2B7B-4416-B528-DA4E0E6A6706}"
EndProject
```

However, as the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37047316) points out, another workaround is to add a **Web Site Project**, which will add a project with no `.csproj` file that keeps track of files on disk "in real time", similar to how the new `.csproj` format works in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Thank you but I'd like to add the files directly in the solution without using a .csproj file.

Comment: See my edit. Solution Files *are* projects, just of a different type.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for. I now added an "ASP.NET Empty Web Site" project and deleted all containing files which eventually is an empty folder without "Properties" and "References".