# EF core database first in Class library using visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, .net-core

Trying to add EF database first in Class library project but it fails and gives an error

> Startup project 'Api.DB.csproj' targets framework '.NETStandard'.
>   There is no runtime associated with this framework, and projects
>   targeting it cannot be executed directly. To use the Entity Framework
>   Core .NET Command Line Tools with this project, add an executable
>   project targeting .NET Core or .NET Framework that references this
>   project, and set it as the startup project using --startup-project;
>   or, update this project to cross-target .NET Core or .NET Framework.

Steps
1. Crete new solution

> dotnet new sln --name TestApi

2. Create Web Api project

> dotnet new webapi --name api

3. Create new class library project

> dotnet new classlib --name Api.DB

4. Add reference of this two project in solution

> dotnet sln "TestApi.sln" add "api/api.csproj"
>
> dotnet sln "TestApi.sln" add "Api.DB/Api.DB.csproj"

5. Add class library project reference in web api project

> PS F:\POC\Projects_POC\EF_Core2_Delete3\api> dotnet add reference ../Api.DB/Api.DB.csproj

6. Add packages in Class library project

> dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
>
> dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
>
> dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
>
> dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design

7. Add Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet in csproj file

> ```
> <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.1"/>
> ```

8. And finally, run scaffold command

> dotnet ef dbcontext Scaffold
>   "Server=GaneshSqlServevr;Database=Car;Trusted_Connection=True;"
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models

The current dotnet version is 2.1.100

and here  Api.DB.csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.5" />
  </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Would changing `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>` to `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>` fix it?

Comment: hello Wubbler it gives me
The specified framework version '2.0' could not be parsed
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      \
  - Alternatively, install the framework version '2.0'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to set-up Entity Framework core in .Net Standard project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48673987)

Comment: Hello  NightOwl888, Its work with Visual Studio 2017 but not in visual studio code

Comment: my current installed version mention as follows 
 <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.0.5</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
 this works for me Thank you  NightOwl888 and  Wubbler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runtime Framework Version works for me, Here is csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.0.5</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.5" />
  </ItemGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following line in your .csproj file to add EF core in a .net core class library project.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
</PropertyGroup>
```