# C# - How to get the directory path of a .NET Standard Library project inside a WPF solution

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a `VS2019` solution that has a `WPF` project referencing a [.NET Standard 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) project included in the same solution. I am using [Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) on the `.NET Standard Library` project where the DbContext class is created as follows.

Because the `MyDbContext.cs` file is inside the Standard Library project, I was expecting `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` directory in the code below to be inside`\bin\Debug\` of the Standard Library project where `MySQLite.db` should have been created . But, on the contrary, it's creating the db inside `\bin\Debug\` of `WPF` project.

**Question**: In the following code how can we make sure the db is created inside Standard Library project's installation directory (bin\Debug) and not inside the startup project `WPF's directory?

**Remark**:

1. Even in `WPF` project it is not really creating a real SQLite db, it's is just creating a file `MySQLite.db` with size `0kb`. And that is probably happening because all the db related files (dbContext, classes, etc) are in Standard Library project.
2. And I finally noticed that `PM>Update-Database -Project MyStandardLibraryProj` NuGet command actually is creating the real MySQLite.db with all the tables etc. at a strange location: `C:\Users\MyUserName\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools\3.1.4\tools\net461\any\MySQLite.db`

**MyDbContext.cs** file `inside .NET Standard Library` Project:

```
……...
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
…...
namespace MyStandardLibraryProj
{
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        string sSQLiteDbPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "MySQLiteDb.db");
        public DbSet<MyObject> MyObjects{ get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) => options.UseSqlite($"Data Source = {sSQLiteDbPath}");
    }
}
```

Comment: The dll of your library will be in the same folder as your exe, unless you' ve installed the dll in the gac or some such. By defailt, when you reference a library then it's dll is copied into your bin folder when you compile. When you install an app i'd expect the dll to be alongside the entry point exe. But all this is kind of academic. Your db should go in the user's appdata folder structure somewhere. A user will not be able to write to a file located under program files. Unless they're using win xp.

Comment: A .NET Standard library doesn't have any "installation directory". Where did you get this from? It's a library that is meant to be consumed by an .exe that targets a .NET runtime that implements the .NET Standard specification. The only bin/debug directory that is interesting during runtime is the one where your .exe resides.