# Project X targets framework '.NETStandard'. The Entity Framework Package Manager Console Tools don't support this framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to create a EF 6.4 migration in my solution which has net472 projects and netstandard projects, and I'm getting the following error:

> Project 'ESP.Console' targets framework '.NETStandard'. The Entity Framework Package Manager Console Tools don't support this framework.

However, the 'ESP.Console' app doesn't target .NETStandard, it's targetting net472:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I have `ESP.Console` console app set as my startup project, and I have the `ESP.Data` project as my default project in the Package Manager console.

This is the setup for `ESP.Data.csproj`:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.1;net472</TargetFrameworks>
    <EmbeddedResourceUseDependentUponConvention>true</EmbeddedResourceUseDependentUponConvention>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I need this to target both netstandard and net472 while I am in the process of converting other applications in the solution to run on .net core.

Why am I getting this error? Is there another command like `dotnet ef` I can use that will work with my EF 6.4 project?

We've used EF migrations on this solution hundreds of times, but since the last time I needed to run a migration we've done two major changes to the solution- converted all the csproj files to use the new format (with PackageReference, etc) and converted the core projects to target either .net standard 2.0 or 2.1 where needed. So I think the issue is related to that.

Attempting to change ESP.Console application to run as `netcoreapp3.1` gave the same error.

Comment: I think "dotnet ef " is for Core only.  In VS try "Add-Migration InitialCreate -Namespace Your.Namespace" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: @Greg that's what I thought. In VS I ran this command: add-migration OrderEventMigration -Namespace ESP.Data.Migrations but this gave me the error:
Add-Migration : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Namespace'.

Comment: it should be as simple as add-migration test. Have a look at https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-based-migration-in-code-first.aspx. I assume you've done enabled migrations?

Comment: Yup we've used this project for migrations plenty before, and add-migration usually worked. Over the past few months we migrated our solution to use the new csproj format and converted the core librararies to use .net standard instead of just net472. I haven't done a migration in a while and when I tried to today I'm getting this error message

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48673987/trying-to-set-up-entity-framework-core-in-net-standard-project - maybe the issue is that the net 472 doesn't have an executable?

Comment: I showed in the question that it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem, though it is a bit messy since I will need to make a temporary change to a csproj file in order to get this to run.

In my case, the `ESP.Data` (the project housing my `DbContext`) was targeting both `net472` and `netstandard2.1`, I altered the Data project to remove the `netstandard2.1` target framework. It seems there is a bug in VS that is saying that the StartupProject targets NetStandard instead of saying that the Target project does. After I create the migration, I can add the target back again.

I will be moving to .net core compilation soon, and will therefore need that netstandard 2.1 target at some point, so I'm not sure what I'll do when that comes. I may need to preserve a net472 console application to use in the future and continue targeting net472 in my data project after that migration is done in order to continue to create migrations.

Answer (score 0):

I had a simular problem. 
My problem was, that I was targeting `netcoreapp3.1` with my startup project and used `Entity Framework 6 tools`. 
When I switched to `EntityFrameworkCore tools` it worked.

Comment: I don't see an "EntityFrameworkCore tools" when I go to Tools > Get Tools and Components > Individual Components. Am I not looking in the right place? VS2022 17.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bug in Visual Studio -- I was seeing this error after I changed the Startup Project to the correct project with my migrations, even though my project uses .NET Framework 4.8.

Tried several things with no luck, but then closing and re-opening Visual Studio fixed the problem.

Comment: Still seeing this behavior in 2022-12 with Visual Studio 2022

Answer (score -1):

I have this problem exactly and found the answer.
I use class library (.NETStandard) but necessary class library (.NET MVC)

With this class library my proj work correct

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).