# How to discover .js, .css files, what are in the filesystem (and repo) but not in .csproj?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, deployment, publish

**Context**

I regularly make the mistake to forget include a vendor .css or .js to the Asp Mvc project. I just copy/download with a tool, or from a theme, and referencing them. All works locally because the files are in the virtual directory so IIS Express will server them.

When publish times come, and I publish the new version, those files which are not in the .csproj will not be deployed.

**Question**

Although some tools or itself the IDE creates warning in *some cases* if in a syntax construct I refer to a resource what is not in the .csproj, this is not all working (for example: when using BundleConfig)
It seems to be pretty simple prevent this source of errors: Just check the file system with a well picked filter and list all files what are not included in the .csproj. (the filter could be: (*.css, *.js, ...) or (assets/*.*)

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: You can just do cross-verify in the solution explorer. It lists down only the solution mapped files by default

Comment: well, there are hundreds... in zillion folders. I use currently a better approach which is still not efficient enough: I turn on "show all files" in solution explorer, so I will see what is not included. Still takes minutes to open all folders, subfolders. If there was an inverse filter, like show only not included, that would be perfect

Comment: which version you are using? VS 2015?

Comment: I am using VS 2017

Comment: you'd have to write some sort of script which parses the csproj file (it's XML)and reads what files are included in the project, and then reads the relevant folders, gets a list of files and compares them to the project list. You can do that in a c# console app maybe.

Comment: in future try to use nuget packages to install extras into your app wherever possible, then the right files always get added to your project automatically. Or just take a bit more care when adding things!

Answer (score 3):

If you switch to the [new `.csproj` format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/migration/) supported by Visual Studio 2017, you no longer need to add references to files in the file system, they are **picked up by default** and you have to **exclude** files that you don't want.

Migration to the new `.csproj` format is pretty straightforward - you can use the [dotnet migrate tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/migration/#dotnet-migrate) to make the conversion.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net47</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProj\MyProj.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>

    <!-- /* Exclude files you don't want */ -->
    <Compile Remove="Text\AnyTransliterator.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Text\BreakTransliterator.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

If you have files **outside** of your project directory that you want to include, you can create a link to a file or directory.

```
<!-- /* Link to an individual file outside of the project */ -->
<Content Include="..\..\..\Assets\something.css" Link="Assets\something.css" />

<!-- /* Create a virtual directory in Visual Studio named Assets
        and link to external Assets directory. All files in that
        directory will be included in the project */ -->
<Content Include="..\..\..\Assets\**\*" LinkBase="Assets" />

<!-- /* Create a virtual directory in Visual Studio named Assets
        and link to external Assets directory. Only .css files in that
        directory will be included in the project */ -->
<Content Include="..\..\..\Assets\**\*.css" LinkBase="Assets" />
```

This **works with .NET Framework**, but do note that you need to install the .NET Core SDK 2.0.0 in addition to VS 2017 15.3 (and ensure no `global.json` selects a lower SDK version) for the `LinkBase` option to work.

**Reference:** [New .csproj format - How to specify entire directory as "linked file" to a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45800697)

Comment: I like this answer, but still doesn't solve OP problem, is there any tool to migrate?

Comment: If the files are automatically added to the `.csproj` file by default or by external reference, they will also be automatically deployed with the project. Isn't that the OP's concern?

Comment: Yea, but it isn't easy to migrate a `.csproj` file. Also, the link specifies for core projects.

Comment: No, the link specifies that you need the .NET Core SDK, but it will compile .NET Framework targets - `<TargetFrameworks>net47</TargetFrameworks>`. And it is not that difficult to migrate - there is a [tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/migration/#dotnet-migrate) to automate most of it.

Comment: Thanks, That's what I wanted to know.

Comment: I'll add it to the answer.